# CSS circular menu

Tags: html, css

I get some HTML and CSS code.
https://codepen.io/lbebber/pen/pvwZJp

```css
.menu-item,
.menu-open-button {
  background: #00bcd4;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
}
```

I tried to use this code, but I did not succeed pushing the hamburger menu to be at the bottom-left corner.
I think something outside the part I copied here is blocking the menu to get it to the bottom.

The second thing, I wanted to use little pictures instead of icons.
Do you have an idea how?
When I add a picture, I am getting weird behavior.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I recommend all new users visit [ask] for tips on writing posts that best enable the community to provide assistance.  Two notes about this post: **(1)** - [Please refrain from linking to your code on third party sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/6831341); instead, try to create a [mcve] in the body of the question that reproduces the problem, and **(2)** - Please refrain from asking more than one question in a post; if you have two questions, make two posts.  For more info you can visit the [help]. Good luck, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is Fixed!

So in your .menu attribute, I added the following. These attributes move your menu (.menu) in a fixed position in the bottom left of the screen.

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 998;
```

I removed the margin-left:-80px; as this caused your menu to warp halfway off the left of the screen when I added the other attributes above. So your .menu attribute should look like this when the proper attributes are edited:

```
.menu{
  @extend %goo;
  $width:650px;
  $height:150px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 998;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:80px;
  width:$width;
  height:$height;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-size:20px;
  text-align:left;
}
```

This resulted (on codepen) with your site looking like this. Of course, the gooey menu opens as shown below. I cannot insert the code into stack overflow as there were issues with layout and content. But if you make the changes to your CSS code above, you can see your menu working

[image: Codepen User Made Website]
[[image: Codepen User Made Website - 2]

Comment: I did not understand all your code but I will later.
Thank you.
About a picture instead of an icon, do you have an idea?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just edited my post to explain the changes made in your CSS code. For your picture question, could you please elaborate?